# how sample android source codes are smaller than hello world android source code in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created hello world android application in eclipse with just one java main activity and one xml layout file without any images in drawable folder ,i removed all the themes from values with default theme.When i saw size of source code it was 2.9 mb in size, and apk file size was 380 kb.But when i opened sample android application in eclipse after running it i checked the file size of source it was 390 kb and apk size was 58 kb,and it had 6 java files in src folder with 3 xml files in layout and couple of images in drawable folder.How come hello world program with nothing be so large than notepad application.I am using eclipse juno as editor.If any one knows the answer please help me.

Comment: Good question! I am following this post now

Comment: Can you show the package structure through an image or some way ?

Comment: Have you checked the SDK version of both the app that you are referring. I am very curious to know the reason. Please share your observations in this post.

Comment: As none of us here have access to your computer it's impossible to give an accurate answer. You, however, can very easily use a file explorer to go through all of the folders in the project and work out what is taking so much space.

Comment: In all computers its the same, once u created the application just see the size of source code. ..

Answer (score 0):

Friends i got the answer for my question,its because we are using library android-support-v4.jar in libs folder and also in apk.This jar file is of no use when writing small applications like hello world.And also This will appear in libs and android private library so the source code size and apk size will increase gradually.